# publish actions : no more ID in error message when error.code equals 3501

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

until today, when my app try to publish an action/object for a user that has already done this action, then in the response.error.message we were able to retreive the ID of the related already existing action.
Today, this information has been removed from the message :
    (#3501) User is already associated to the  object on a unique action type Read. ID: xxxxxxxxx
became
    (#3501) User is already associated to the  object on a unique action type Read.

So here is my question : how to retreive the action id for a specific url.
I tried this (following a post in this forum) but it doesn't work because it returns a set of data (and i don't want to browse all page before finding the one i'm looking for)

```
FB.api(
    '/me/news.reads?article=myURL',
    'get',
    function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error: ' + response.error.type + ' - ' + response.error.message);
            console.log(response);
        } else {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems that the response is now coming back to the old way, and i receive again the ID...

Sorry for convenience, but if there is a way to retreive action id based on url that would be easier.